# How did the amount of nuclide produced by s- and r-process changed over time?

Tags: nucleosynthesis

For a exercise I need to find out how the amount of nuclide produced by s- and r-process changed over time and I also need to draw a schematic diagram of the s-/r-ratio vs. time from 13.6 Ga till today and explain my reasoning. I searched for an answer in my lecture notes and also the lecture but I can't find a solution for this problem. Can somebody help me out where I could find an answer for this?

Comment: That's a rather broad question! Since this is for an exercise, you should include in your question your thoughts on this topic. Think about what has changed over time that *could* affect the amount of nuclides produced by the s- & r-processes. There are some useful hints in the first two paragraphs of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-process

Comment: Homework question. You need to think about what processes/types of stars produce each type of element, when the progenitors of these were born, how long they lived, and what the star formation rate is as a function of time.